# what the meaning of variable int b[]

Tags: c

#### file a.c

```
int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10};
int *b = a;
```

#### file b.c version one

```
extern int a[];
extern int b[];
a[2] = 1; //works well
b[2] = 1; //works well
```

#### file b.c version two

```
extern int *a;
extern int b[];
a[2] = 1; // segfault
b[2] = 1; // works well
```

`extern int b[]` matches `int *b`, while `extern int a[]` matches `int a[10]`, why int[] both matches `int *b`(a pointer) and `int a[10]` (an array) at the same time?

PS: int b[] will throw out an compile error in codeblocks, and a warning in gcc.

Comment: i guess its a `pointer`, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: Why does everyone down vote and assume the world is an expert?

Comment: [] and * are interchangeable when not used to declare a variable.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with: expecting C to have type safety is dangerous practice. Using global variables is bad and dangerous practice. Your program is combining these two dangerous practices.

When you write

```
  extern int a[];
  extern int b[];
```

you tell the compiler that these two variables are allocated elsewhere and that it should not concern it's pretty head about where and how.

Then you declare these variables in another file, but not according to the specification you gave the compiler. Instead you changed one variable to a pointer instead of an array. But since C have non-existant type safety, this will compile still. Therefore it is your responsibility to ensure that a and b have the right types.

`a[2]=1` will of course work just fine, because `a` is externally defined as an allocated array.

`b[2]=1` will however not work at all, you'll invoke undefined behavior.

Because the compiler will treat the chunk of memory where you stored `b` as an array. But what's actually stored there is a pointer containing the address of `a`. At index [0] this might work, you'll simply destroy the pointer variable. But at index [1] you'll write at an invalid memory location.

The solution is to never use global variables and `extern` (unless the variable is `const`).

Comment: *a[2]=1 will of course work just...* For what example are you talking about there? First or second.

Comment: +1 for "it should not concern it's pretty head about where and how"

Comment: @self. There was only one example when I posted this, so the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A difference between

```
int a[]
int *b;
```

is that 'a' is a compiler name to access an array, where as, 'b' is an int pointer.  'b' can be reassigned to point to any int.  One affect is that 'a' cannot be reassigned, but 'b' can be.

For example,

```
b = a; //Is Legal
int c[] = {1};
a = c; //Is NOT Legal
```

Also, in most contexts in later use, a mention of the variable 'a' is converted to a pointer to the first item in the array.

Next, the 'extern' key word simply tells the compiler not to allocate memory for the given variable because it is defined elsewhere.  Therefore, the extern 'a' and 'b' in file b.c simply makes the variables 'a' and 'b' in file a.c available to file b.c.